# HDD mount. wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc,

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I lost power to my desktop PC and one HDD got some errors after power-on. On GUI it doesn't show me that HDD. On the terminal, I got this error:

```
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

lsblk -l show only /dev/sdc

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdc: 2,7 TiB, 3000591900160 bytes, 5860531055 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1           1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.



$ parted -l

Error: Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sdc
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? i                                                    
Error: The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
OK/Cancel?                                                                
OK/Cancel? OK                                                             
Model: ATA TOSHIBA HDWD130 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:


gdisk -l /dev/sdc

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Warning! Disk size is smaller than the main header indicates! Loading
secondary header from the last sector of the disk! You should use 'v' to
verify disk integrity, and perhaps options on the experts' menu to repair
the disk.
Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************
Disk /dev/sdc: 5860531055 sectors, 2.7 TiB
Model: TOSHIBA HDWD130 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 190FB3A2-F875-425D-85F4-4979BA8E5AAE
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 5860533134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2925 sectors (1.4 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      5860532223   2.7 TiB     8300  3tB_01_name
```

Any words of wisdom on how to fix that HDD ?! There was only one partition on that drive and data that will be nice not to lose!

Comment: Please update your question with the exact  command you are using. You shouldn't be mounting /dev/sdc but /dev/sdc1 !!

Comment: in few first lines, I wrote: lsblk -l show only /dev/sdc

$ ll /dev/sd* shows others drives all ok but only sdc no sdc1

Comment: `/dev/sdc` is the physical disk, `/dev/sdc1` (an `/dev/sdc2` and so on if defined), are the partitions defined on the disk. It is partitions you mount. Your output from `fdisk` shows that there are one partition, `/dev/sdc1`.

Comment: i move hdd to laptop so i can do more work on it and now is sdb
root @ lateralus in ~ |13:25:43  
$ mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/
mount: /mnt: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist.
root @ lateralus in ~ |13:26:04  
$ mount /dev/sdb /mnt/
mount: /mnt: mount(2) system call failed: Structure needs cleaning.
root @ lateralus in ~ |13:26:21